# Foreignkey return object instead of self.name

Tags: django, django-models

I have found several answers that look like my problem, but are not. Maybe I a missing something here, but here goes;

I want a model to return as default the name of the foreignkey item it is linked to.

This is the coupling table

```
class CharacterTrait(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?

    id_character = models.ForeignKey(Werewolfcharacter, null=True, db_column = 'id_character')
    id_trait     = models.ForeignKey(Trait,             null=True, db_column = 'id_trait')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'character_trait'

    def __unicode__(self):
                return self.id_trait
```

This is the Trait table

```
class Trait(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField? 
    id_traittype = models.ForeignKey(Traittype, null=True, db_column = 'id_traittype')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'trait'

    def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

So, when I would ask for the return value, I'd expect when I call upon CharacterTrait to get back the name of the linked Trait. But, when I go to the admin, I get this error;

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Trait found
```

But when it finds Trait, shouldn't it return the Trait.name? Obviously, it doesn't, otherwise I would not be asking this question.

Also, when I do this in CharacterTrait;

def **unicode**(self):
            return self.id_trait.name

I get back this;

```
[<CharacterTrait: Homid>]
```

Which is what I want, but only the string "Homid" and not as a model.

Comment: how about ``return self.id_trait.name`` ?

Answer (score 1):

In `CharacterTrait` model's unicode method your are returning `Trait` object instead of string/unicode object.

So update your method as below to return string.

```
class CharacterTrait(models.Model):
   ...
    def __unicode__(self):
          return u'' + self.id_trait
```

Comment: That did not work. I get the same error. Exception Value: 
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Trait found

Answer (score 1):

the `__unicode__` method must return a unicode

```
class CharacterTrait(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
      return unicode(self.id_trait)  # this will call Trait.__unicode__
```

Answer (score 0):

`__str__` will return the value from a class. 
replace the field name with your field in below code which you want.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```